# using AndEngine in Android Studio 0.2.10

Tags: android, andengine, android-studio

I'm trying to develop application's Android platform, so far I have programmed in PHP / MySQL, VB.Net, C #, and I have extensive knowledge and experience in this area, I decided to go in developing applications for Android (some of my clients have requirements for such applications). Programming for android I choose android studio (perhaps my decision is wrong), I use the latest version of Android studio (0.2.10) and I install all the SDK and ADT (following the tutorials I googled) and it works.

But currently I am suffering with the installation of AndEngine to Android Studio and compile in AndEngine in Android Studio

I'm trying to add the latest version of AndEngine from github again following tutorials (I googled for it)

Does anyone have any instructions on how to use AndEngine Android Studio 0.2.10, because everything I googled is for older versions of Android studios and i can't get andengine.jar file (which i need ) that can later be used in the studio as Android library

Excuse my bad English (if)

Comment: I had been suffering with this too, what I ended up doing was making the project in eclipse IDE and importing the andengine and extensions, then importing this project into android studio. Been working like that ever since

Comment: Hello, Thanks for reply, i also start in this direction, import andengine in eclipse and probably i'll continue to work in eclipse, will see

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample project I used to get AndEngine working in Android Studio.

https://github.com/janebabra/TowerofHanoiProject

All you have to do is add the andengine.jar to your own project and reference it in the project and the Gradle build config.

Hope that helps